# Why pip install colorama~=0.3 installs colorama-0.4.0

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have trouble installing my project which depends on Colorama.
In the `setup.py`, I specified:

```
'colorama ~= 0.3'
```

But I’m surprised to see that the version 0.4 is installed (this version is new).

How to reproduce?
Create and activate a virtualenv and run:

```
pip install colorama~=0.3
```

And then look at the logs or run:

```
pip list
```

What’s wrong with the `~=` operator?

*note:* I'm using pip v18.1 and setuptools v40.4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator `~=` means "compatible release". When using [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) a compatible version is such that the first number in the sequence is the same (number 0 in this case).

From the link above:

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> **MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,** MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner,
>   and PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

Comment: Do you have any reference regarding pip or setuptools documentation? No sure you are right, so I need more information…

Comment: You can see it in the following example: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#example-requirements-file The dependecy speficication is defined in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/ and the versioning scheme in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-scheme

Comment: OK Arturo, I think I should use `colorama==0.3.*` (or `colorama~=0.3.0`) instead.

Comment: Personally, I would use a fixed version so the result code will always be the same just in case the dependencies are installed again